# How to sort sqlalchemy table with python function?

Tags: python, sql, numpy, sqlalchemy

I have table with column equation, on this column I store mathematical equation like `x+12-25+z**2`, `x*z-12`, etc. for each row it is different equation and I want to sort my table by equation's output. X and Z are some python variables, you can think of them as `numpy.array`. Variables are updated every 15-30 minutes.

 My table looks like this

```
class Table(Base):
   ....
   equation = Column(String(1024))
```

I calculate equations in python by my function `calculate_equation(string)` it takes care of the placing all variables and doing math operations also it returns only 1 number.

I tried with `hybrid_property` which looks like this:

```
@hybrid_property
def equation_value(self):
   return calculate_equation(self.equation)
```

And sort it with:

```
session.query(Table).order_by(Table.equation_value).all()
```

But it throws errors.
Any advises on how to do it? Is this even correct? Should I use other data storing mechanism?

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Probably relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074207/can-order-by-work-with-properties-from-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.order_by()` method emits an SQL `ORDER BY` clause; so the thing you're ordering by needs to be an SQL expression, not an arbitrary python function. Just tagging the method with `@hybrid_property` isn't enough - you need to also implement `@equation_value.expression` as an sqlalchemy expression.

You have two options:

- Implement your `calculate_equation` function in SQL (or as an sqlalchemy expression/hybrid prop), which will allow you to use it in an `ORDER BY` clause. From your description, this is probably very difficult.
- Just query for everything and do the sorting afterwards in memory:

```py
sorted(session.query(Table).all(), key=calculate_equation)
```

Comment: I decided to store values from my function in separate column and update table when variables are updated. What do you think?